# Container cannot be resolved or not a field

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm learning to program for Android using the official tutorial

I'm in section **Building a Simple User Interface**, but I can't run the final application.

```
Container cannot be resolved or not a field
```

I googled a bit but I couldn't find any useful solutions.

Here's my code is:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Did you define your container in the XML page? Usually I think its a framelayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `activity_main` layout should have a view group (such as `FrameLayout`) with the id `container`.

This is explained in a [later training](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html).

The error comes from this piece of code trying to refer to the `container` resource id:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
            .commit();
```

Currently ADT wizards generate code like this; the guides are written for earlier ADT versions in mind where the generated code was slightly different.