# How to fix 'cannot be resolved or is not a type' error using Android Tutorial code?

Tags: android

As suggested in other threads, I am following a [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html) in order to learn the basics of android application development. However, the code for the `DisplayMessageActivity` class [as given here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) contains several errors:

- container can not be resolved or is not a field (line 16)
- Fragment cannot be resolved into a type (line 37)
- View cannot be resolved into a type (line 62)
- fragment_display_message cannot be resolved or is not a type (line 62).
- Wile trying to fix this error by my own a new error popped up out of nowhere at line 55: `Class requires API level 11 (current min is 8);android.app.Fragment`

According to another [SO entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272075/container-cannot-be-resloved-or-not-a-field) this is due to an ADT version mismatch. But this entry does not explain how to fix it.

How can this tutorial code be fixed so it compiles - or is there a 'working' tutorial available somewhere with actual working examples?

Here is the code so far:

```
package com.example.testapp;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
//
//        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
//            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
//                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
//                .commit();
//        }

        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() { }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_message,
                      container, false);
              return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the content of the file `res/layout/activity_main.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
     <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:onClick="sendMessage" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and here the content of the file `res/layout/activity_display_message.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.testapp.DisplayMessageActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Addendum:

- I tried to include missing libraries, and now most of the errors turned into a grey 'X' (which, I guess, is now a mere warning and can be ignored? Should it be fixed? If so, how?)
- The error regarding `fragment_display_message` stays as error, probably it is not defined (contrary to the example given.)

Comment: Alex can you make the title a bit more specific to the problem at hand ?

Comment: @Ayub: I hope it is more specific.

Comment: and please put the entire log-cat error message and the code you've written so far as well

Comment: How to get the content of the log-cat?

Comment: can you see DDMS on top right corner of the eclipse?

Comment: What is a DDMS? I have the Log-Cat open, but I only see 'D's...

Comment: from Eclipse, click on WINDOW -> OPEN PERSPECTIVE -> DDMS, at the bottom you should see LogCat tab, with all the messages, copy messages in RED and paste them here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57347/discussion-between-alex-and-ayub).

Answer (score 3):

I was working my way through the same tutorial and I ran in to many of the same issues as you. One in particular had me stumped for an hour. I finally figured it out and here you go.

The error that the both of us got was the following:

`fragment_display_message cannot be resolved or is not a type (line 62).`

The fix is relatively simple, the reference to `fragment_display_message` should get changed to `activity_display_message`. Your new line in `DisplayMessageActivity` should now look like this:

`View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_display_message, container, false);`